# How to set up for tributes as Zheng Jiang?

Tags: three-kingdoms-total-war

I can't force factions to pay me tributes. I'm around turn 70, I'm checking most turns for tributes (in the quick deal menu mostly) but so far I only managed to do it once. And the faction turned against me and stopped paying a few turn later anyway (I think it was vassalized). They all are strictly refusing without any room to negotiate.

I tried crushing factions and leaving them with only one or two territories after defeating all their armies. Even sacked all their territories to try. They still refuse.

I read tributes are for big factions, annoy them by taking or looting a few settlements and beat their armies; they may be ready to pay tributes to get you off their back. So I tried once but without success.

I read that you can't ask tributes to vassals, so as Yuan Shao vassalized half of china already, it may be the reason.
The early game was harsh, and I had a single army constantly fighting while recuperating. So I may not have been very imposing, but a lot of time there were factions way weaker than me that still refused.
I entered a coalition with Cao Cao and Dong Zhuo's heir (which are powerful factions in my game) but it made no difference.

**What are the favorable/unfavorable factors in asking for tributes ?**

*edit*: A bit after turn 80, I had managed to raise a second army and crushed again a neighbor. Took five of his ten territories, beat his 3 armies and he was open for a tribute this time. The turn after, another faction (that I could not even see on the map) was open for a tribute... I didn't want to disappoint them so I accepted.
I think you don't solely need to be a threatening force relatively to your target, but also globally. Right now there are a few factions with similar strength (and allies strength) as me, but none superior.